# instantiate class from string and invoke method

Tags: python

For example I've got some string with class definition

```
ext_class = """
    class ExtClass(IntClass): 
        def method(self):
            print 'Invokation'
    """
```

Is it possible to instantiate class from that string and invoke its method?

Comment: [`exec`ute](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec_stmt) it.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary but in that case - how can I access it? Or after `exec` I can use it as is?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Oh! Indeed I can! Thanks!